# rpart stops at root node and does not split further when there is an obvious information gain

Tags: r, rpart

I am trying to use rpart to build a classification tree model.
The test data frame is very simple containing only two boolean variables in 10 rows.
The hidden logic is simple too: when x is FALSE, y must be FALSE.  When x is TRUE, y has 60% chance of being TRUE.
So I would imagine rpart would do one split on x to increase node purity.  But it stays at root node and does not split at all. Anyone please advise?

```
> df <- data.frame(x=rep(c(FALSE,TRUE), each=5), y=c(rep(FALSE,7), rep(TRUE,3)))
> df
       x     y
1  FALSE FALSE
2  FALSE FALSE
3  FALSE FALSE
4  FALSE FALSE
5  FALSE FALSE
6   TRUE FALSE
7   TRUE FALSE
8   TRUE  TRUE
9   TRUE  TRUE
10  TRUE  TRUE
> rpart(y~x, method='class', data=df)
n= 10 

node), split, n, loss, yval, (yprob)
      * denotes terminal node

1) root 10 3 FALSE (0.7000000 0.3000000) *
```

Comment: N = 10? That is pruning! Rpart is avoiding overfitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, this is meant to avoid overfitting. Formally, there is the argument `minsplit`, which is preset to 20 but can be adjusted to give the result you seek:

```
> library(rpart)
> df <- data.frame(x=rep(c(FALSE,TRUE), each=5), y=c(rep(FALSE,7), rep(TRUE,3)))
> rpart(y ~ x, data=df, minsplit=2)
n= 10 

node), split, n, deviance, yval
      * denotes terminal node

1) root 10 2.1 0.3  
  2) x< 0.5 5 0.0 0.0 *
  3) x>=0.5 5 1.2 0.6 *
```

find more arguments to avoice overfitting (i. e. `cp` and `maxdepth`) in

```
help(rpart.control)
```

*EDIT: With method="class" the output changes to*

```
> rpart(y ~ x, data=df, minsplit=2, method="class")
n= 10 

node), split, n, loss, yval, (yprob)
      * denotes terminal node

 1) root 10 3 FALSE (0.7000000 0.3000000)  
  2) x< 0.5 5 0 FALSE (1.0000000 0.0000000) *
  3) x>=0.5 5 2 TRUE (0.4000000 0.6000000) *
```

Comment: Thanks.  The test data size is too small.  When I increase it to N=100 rpart behaves as expected.  

    > df <- data.frame(x=rep(c(FALSE,TRUE), each=50), y=c(rep(FALSE,70), rep(TRUE,30)))
    > rpart(y~x, method='class', data=df)
    n= 100 
    
    node), split, n, loss, yval, (yprob)
          * denotes terminal node
    
    1) root 100 30 FALSE (0.7000000 0.3000000)  
    2) x< 0.5 50  0 FALSE (1.0000000 0.0000000) *
    3) x>=0.5 50 20 TRUE (0.4000000 0.6000000) *

Comment: But it still does not work for the following:

    > df <- data.frame(x=rep(c(FALSE,TRUE), each=50), y=c(rep(FALSE,80), rep(TRUE,20)))
    > rpart(y~x, method='class', data=df)

Comment: `tree <- rpart(y~x, data=df, cp=-1)` will do in a sensible way, `tree <- rpart(y~x, method='class', data=df, cp=-1)` in a less sensible way.