# Decision tree always predicting class Label as Yes

Tags: r, machine-learning, decision-tree

I am trying the fit the decision tree model on a small dataset in R, but it is always predicting class label as Yes, irrespective of whatever dataset am giving as input.

Data

```
outlook <- c("sunny", "sunny", "overcast", "rain", "rain", "rain", "overcast", "sunny", "sunny", "rain", "sunny", "overcast", "overcast", "rain")
temperature <- c("hot", "hot", "hot", "mild", "cool", "cool", "cool", "mild", "cool", "mild", "mild", "mild", "hot", "mild")
humidity <- c("high", "high", "high", "high", "normal", "normal", "normal", "high", "normal", "normal", "normal", "high", "normal", "high")
wind <- c("weak", "strong", "weak", "weak", "weak", "strong", "strong", "weak", "weak", "weak", "strong", "strong", "weak", "strong")
class <- c("no", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no")

data <- data.frame(outlook, temperature, humidity, wind, class)
data
```

Encoding the data

```
outlook_new <- as.numeric(as.factor(outlook))
temperature_new <- as.numeric(as.factor(temperature))
humidity_new <- as.numeric(as.factor(humidity))
wind_new <- as.numeric(as.factor(wind))
class_new <- as.numeric(as.factor(class))

data_new <- data.frame(outlook_new, temperature_new, humidity_new, wind_new, class_new)
data_new
```

Building the Model

```
model <- rpart(class_new ~ ., data=data_new)
```

Creating the test data point

```
test_data <- data.frame(outlook_new = 2, temperature_new = 2, humidity_new = 1, wind_new = 1)
test_data
```

Prediction

```
predict(model, test_data, type='response')
```

The predict function is always giving the result as yes, irrespective of the input.

What is the problem?

Comment: Your model isn't finding any splits. Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40313198/rpart-stops-at-root-node-and-does-not-split-further-when-there-is-an-obvious-inf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such a small training set you need to update the model control, and take the results with a pinch of salt!

```
model <- rpart(class ~ ., data = data, control = rpart.control(minsplit = 1))
predict(model, newdata = data, type = 'class')
#   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14 
#  no  no yes yes yes  no yes  no yes yes yes yes yes  no 
# Levels: no yes
```

Comment: Got it. Thank You.